# OLAP Service stopping out of the blue and Not starting immediately when rebooted

Tags: ssas

So I have analysis server installed and the services just get down for some reason also when the server is rebooted. I installed a script binding it to the SSAS service to automatically start when rebooted. this is the script I used:

sc config MSSQLServerOLAPService depend=w32time/netlogon

Even after this, the SSAS service keeps stopping. Please help. This has been very frustrating.

Comment: What does the Windows Event Log show during the times it stops?

Comment: No It doesn't. I tried looking for hours but it doesnt show anything.